# Is it okay to run php artisan :clear commands on a production laravel website?

Tags: php, laravel, server, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I have a production Laravel website hosted on a DigitalOcean NGINX server, and every time I git push new updates, I always run the following commands:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear

composer dump-autoload
```

Is this a good practice, or will running these commands on my server cause issues?

Comment: Why should that cause any issues? Have you seen any?

Comment: Just because I haven’t “seen” any issues, doesn’t mean there is none.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the `clear`s except the `cache` one can be part of your deployment script.

But running `php artisan cache:clear` in production is super risky and cause unexpected results such as losing all of your critical data.

Let's say your cache driver, queue driver, session driver is `redis` and they all share the same redis instance(same host). When you execute `cache:clear` it is going to execute the following method

```
/**
 * Remove all items from the cache.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function flush()
{
    $this->connection()->flushdb();

    return true;
}
```

What it does is executing the `flushdb` command of redis. It is going to flush the session of all the users, all the queued jobs, all the cached items, all the broadcast related codes if they are in the same database. Here is the [method](https://redis.io/commands/flushdb)

> Delete all the keys of the currently selected DB. This command never fails.

Edit: If they use the same redis driver + same host but different database then this may not cause side-effect problems but it needs manual configuration of setting different databases for different components.

Comment: What about running composer dump-autoload?

Comment: it can/should be part of your deployment script. Nothing harmful about dump-autoload. @JakeScervino

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Ersoy's answer, but just to add something to the mix

I run these commands on push, rather then using clear, i re-cache the config and route.
Although keep in mind, that route:cache doesn't work with all possible routes, refer to the laravel documentation about that.

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan view:clear

composer install --no-dev
```

Comment: What is the difference between running :cache or :clear?

Comment: clear wipes the data, cache, stores a compiled version of the data, for speed improvements, although i mainly used the config:cache for shared hosting as all the sites share the same env https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/configuration#configuration-caching