# Php artisan not detecting declared route

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and try to run a program. In the source code, the route `login.post` already declared in web.php. however i still getting error `Route [login.post] not defined.`. Is there any missing configuration i missing? I already ran `composer install` and `composer update`. `php artisan db:seed` and `php artisan migrate`.

***web,php***

```
Route::get('login', [AuthController::class, 'index'])->name('login');
Route::post('post-login', [AuthController::class, 'postLogin'])->name('login.post'); 
Route::get('register', [AuthController::class, 'register'])->name('register');
Route::post('post-registration', [AuthController::class, 'postRegistration'])->name('register.post'); 
Route::get('logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');
```

Error pic[image]

Comment: Why do you think it should work? I mean you do assign a name to the route and the route() helper should work with the name, but [the Laravel documentation remains unspecific about the characters and from which character set a name must be and also any length constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#named-routes). Therefore I'd say the behaviour you describe maybe either using the wrong name (e.g. just a typo or little mistake) or implementation specified by the Laravel version you're using. +[Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You may need to clear your route cache: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62979986/laravel-routing-cache - though you _might_ also want to avoid using `.` in your route names... I think they're okay, but not able to check that right now.

Comment: @HorusKol Dots in route names are and have been fine as long as I can remember.

Answer (score 0):

Run `php artisan optimize`
This creates a new cache and it makes your new routes to be detected.
For more information, check this [Laravel 5 Artisan Optimization Commands](https://ckdigital.com/laravel-5-artisan-optimization-commands/#:%7E:text=1.,%3A%20bootstrap%2Fcache%2Fcompiled.)

And check the attached screenshot for how they work.[Using the commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0pAn.png)

Comment: ``php artisan optimize`` does the opposite of what you're saying! It should be ``php artisan optimize:clear`` or ``php artisan route:clear`` to clear route caches or ``php artisan cache:clear`` to clear all caches.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, true. While `php artisan optimize` does not clear the cache, it does the following;

- It caches configuration settings and routes, making them load faster. This means the previous cache is cleared.
- Generates optimized versions of the framework's essential files. These optimized files help improve the performance of your Laravel application.
- Ensures that your application runs efficiently by keeping important data readily available.

I understand that creating a new cache means the previous one is destroyed/deleted first, that's why I recommended that command.